# Redis ERR unknown command 'FLUSHDB'

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, redis

I deployed a laravel application into AWS EC2. The redis server is installed on another EC2 server.

The connection to the redis server is being initialized successfully. But, whenever I attempt to clear the cache, I get this error:

`Predis\Response\ServerException  : ERR unknown command 'FLUSHDB', with args beginning with:`

If I install redis server locally on the application server, it works fine.

Any idea how to fix it?

P.S: I tried two versions of redis: 4.0.9 and 5.0.7 (both gave me the same error)

Comment: Did you install predis? `composer require predis/predis` - In your commandline, try `redis-cli` and `FLUSHDB`. Does it work? Or are you using `phpredis`?

Comment: @sentypredis is installed. Something should be wrong with the redis server. I installed it from AWS marketplace. When I run `FLUSHDB` with redis-cli, I get the `unknown command` error from the redis server. But, if I connect to the local redis, it works

Comment: Sorry but I have no clue :/ hope you figure it out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That means `FLUSHDB` has been disabled. This is a dangerous command, so many admin will disable this command by renaming the command with `rename-command` configuration in `redis.conf` or just disable it by rename it to empty string.

```
rename-command flushdb ""
```

Check the conf file for detail on command renaming.

Comment: Thank you. That was it.
For those who are wondering where the default config file on AWS bitnami instance is, look for `/bitnami/redis/conf/redis.conf`