# REDIS Error: ERR unknown command `CONFIG when trying to set dir

Tags: redis

I'm trying to run the following

```
redis-cli --raw -a '<password censored>' 'CONFIG SET dir /var/www/html'
```

However I keep getting:

```
ERR unknown command `CONFIG SET dir /var/www/html`, with args beginning with:
```

Any advice?

Comment: `CONFIG` has been disabled. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111007/redis-err-unknown-command-flushdb) similar question.

Comment: Maybe someone have used this command `rename-command CONFIG xxxx` OR `rename-command CONFIG ""`, OR you could check your `redis.conf`, if there is settings like `rename-command CONFIG xxx`. This will cause that you can not normally use this command. You can reference to [Disabling of specific commands](https://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands)