# Redis, almost no commands work properly, get Error Unknown command for KNOWN COMMANDS

Tags: redis

Trying to make a SIMPLE backup of our Redis Database that is on Heroku for a Ruby on Rails command, I connect using redis-cli just fine, I can type help save and it says it is a command, but when I try to run save it gives me a lame error that says:

```
ec2-34-231-26-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com:19099> save
(error) ERR unknown command `save`, with args beginning with:
ec2-34-231-26-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com:19099> bgsave
(error) ERR unknown command `bgsave`, with args beginning with:
ec2-34-231-26-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com:19099>
```

Yet if I ask for help on these commands they do in fact exist:

```
ec2-34-231-26-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com:19099> help save

  SAVE -
  summary: Synchronously save the dataset to disk
  since: 1.0.0
  group: server

ec2-34-231-26-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com:19099> help bgsave

  BGSAVE -
  summary: Asynchronously save the dataset to disk
  since: 1.0.0
  group: server

ec2-34-231-26-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com:19099>
```

Does anyone know why Redis doesn't work properly?
It is the Heroku Hobby Dev version and I am connecting to it via Windows which is not giving me ANY trouble at all other than the Redis Server not working properly.  On another instance I get an even stranger error that says Save is not allowed?

I have searched for hours and there appears to be NOTHING on this subject at all which is very confusing to me.  A lot of the commands listed on redis.io return that same stupid error that the command doesn't exist when the help clearly states that it DOES exist.
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redis ERR unknown command 'FLUSHDB'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111007/redis-err-unknown-command-flushdb)

Comment: I suppose it is possible, I will take a look at the config file on Heroku, just have to find it.  TY for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this may help someone, In my case was that there was a rename in the configuration

check your **redis.config** file

I had

```
rename-command SAVE "SV"
```

now, type your rename command and that's it

```
127.0.0.1:6380> SV
OK
```

Comment: not that you implied otherwise, but I don't think redis.config exists/is accessible in the AWS Redis (ElastiCache) case. Only in 'normal' redis

Answer (score 1):

In AWS ElastiCache, some of the REDIS commands are restricted and cannot be used.
One of them is SAVE command.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html